# SQL Query Help—Confused About Quotes and Concatenating

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to wrap my head around writing queries in SQL and I'm having some difficulty understanding this example that I've found.

```
$q = "INSERT INTO `dbUsers` (`username`,`password`,`email`) "
        ."VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."', "
        ."PASSWORD('".$_POST["password"]."'), "
        ."'".$_POST["email"]."')";
```

I guess I'm stumbling over the use of double quotes, single quotes, and the back-ticks. I compared this statement to the example on the W3 website and am just really confused as it seems much more complicated. Could you please explain to me what is going on in the above query? Thank you for your help!

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double quotes surround the strings that will be a part of the query string. The dots between each double-quoted section are the concatenation operator.  They are joining individual string pieces together.
You'll notice that there is a double-quote and dot before every $_POST[] array variable, and  a dot and double-quote after.

e.g. " . $_POST["username"] . "

The first double quote ends the previous string section.  The one at the end starts the next string section.  Everything between the two dots is the POST variable.  The reason the dots are necessary is because of the quotes around "username".  In your W3 version they did not use quotes around the $_POST[] array key string (e.g. $_POST[firstname] and not $_POST["firstname"] or $_POST['firstname']) and so they did not need to use dots and quotes.

If you want to keep things simple, don't use the quotes inside of the $_POST[] variables and you won't have to use all those dots and quotes around them.

If you try version 1 without the dots and quotes the php parser will fail and you will see an error.

Comment: @Vecta I should also add that, according to php.net, you _should_ always use quotes around a string inside the [] brackets of an array variable, although the chances of something going wrong are probably small.  [Read here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar) under "Why is $foo[bar] wrong" for more details.

Answer (score 5):

The double quotes are used to define the elements that build your `$q` string. The single quotes identify strings *within* the SQL query that you are building and the backticks are used to escape object names in MySQL.

Comment: ... and in this case, the backticks are useless as none of the escaped names are reserved words in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Backticks ` are to escape MySQL keywords (usually used for table and column names). Single or double quotes are required around any strings which are inserted.

Note that you should call `mysql_real_escape_string` on any string you're concatenating into a SQL query. Otherwise, it's possible to break out of quotes if `$_POST` also includes quotes. This can potentially be used to allow the execution of arbitrary SQL commands in what is known as a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack.

Answer (score 1):

The `back ticks` are optionally used to quote mysql field names, you will need them if you accidentally use one of mysqls reserved words to name a field - otherwise you don't need them.

When you enter a string into a field you have to 'quote it'.

The whole statement has to be quoted, but not clash with 2) above, hence the use of "double quotes".

Non scalar values such as arrays do not automatically expand, so you have to "drop out" . and . "back in" to PHP to build your string using concatenation sign a dot .

Answer (score 1):

The backticks are a MySQL artifact in case you are using reserved words as your table/field names, and the single quotes delineate string literals in SQL. The double quotes are PHP-specific and separate strings in PHP. So, your query below would look like the following:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES
('".$_POST["firstname"]."','".$_POST["lastname"]."','".$_POST["age"]."')";
```

One thing that the author above is doing is also breaking the PHP string into separate strings, probably to improve readability. MySQL server doesn't care about that.

Answer (score 1):

- The double quotes are part of the PHP code, telling it that the items inside the double quotes are strings. They're not part of the SQL being built.
- The single quotes are used to surround values in the resulting SQL. Ie, you're telling the database the value "bob" is used here. For some types of value (integers, boolean, etc) you don't need the single quotes. For many others (varchar, dates, etc), you need the single quotes.
- The backticks perform much the same function as single quotes, except they're used around table names, field names, etc... rather than around actual values. They're used when the name in question wouldn't be interpreted by the database correctly there, for example if you had a field named `count, since that's a keyword in SQL. As noted elsewhere, the backticks aren't necessary in your example, but many people put them in all the time because it doesn't hurt to have them; as a safety net, kindof.`

To give a visible, simpler example

```
$name = "bob";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `name` = '" . $name . "'";
```

This would result in the `$sql` variable being

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `name` = 'bob'
```

As you can see, the double quotes are not part of the string.. they're just used in creating it. In the resulting SQL, the backticks surround the table/field names, and the single quotes surround the actual value bob.

*As a complete side note, using the POST values directly in created SQL is dangerous as it allows for SQL injection attacks. The values should be escaped or a parametrized query should be used.*

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a lot of unnecessary stuff in that first query.  There are best practices to take into account but it could be re-written as such:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO dbUsers (username, password, email)
    VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."',
    PASSWORD('".$_POST["password"]."'),
    '".$_POST["email"]."')";
```

First thing: `INSERT INTO dbUsers`:

- All this is doing is telling us what table we're inserting our data into.

`(username, password, email)`

- Specifying the columns we're inserting into (order specific)

`VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."', PASSWORD('".$_POST["password"]."'), '".$_POST["email"]."')`

- Our values to be inserted (dependent on the order of the columns), then a terminating semicolon.

If you re-write this with hard coded values rather than concatenation, it would look like:

`VALUES ('myUserName', PASSWORD('myPassword'), 'myEmail')`

All of that should be self explanitory.  Each value is contained within single quotes (') as they are strings.  Then the password value is passed through the MySQL function `PASSWORD` which hashed the password for security purposes.